# Change cursor of a imagebutton set from cs page?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, gridview

I am setting an image on grid view on row data bound ..In same rows image will show in some it dont . so i am adding it from CS page based on business logic .I just want to show the cursor as hand ? how to change the style of image icon.

```
if (e.Row.Cells[16].Text == "0")
                        {
                            e.Row.Cells[16].Text = string.Empty;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ImageButton img1 = new ImageButton();
                            img1.ImageUrl = "images/ablue.GIF";
                            img1.Height = 14;
                            img1.Width = 20;
                            img1.ToolTip = "Image Available";
                            img1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return SetId('" + e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString() + "');");
                            e.Row.Cells[16].Controls.Add(img1);
                        }
```

Here image is howing but not in hand cursor .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

"imageButtonClass";**

```
 if (e.Row.Cells[16].Text == "0")
      {
           e.Row.Cells[16].Text = string.Empty;
      }
      else
      {
           ImageButton img1 = new ImageButton();
           img1.ImageUrl = "images/ablue.GIF";
           img1.Height = 14;
           img1.Width = 20;
           img1.ToolTip = "Image Available";
           img1.cssClass = "imageButtonClass";
           img1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return SetId('" + e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString() + "');");
           e.Row.Cells[16].Controls.Add(img1);
      }
```

In Extrnal CSS or style :

img1.cssClass

```
.imageButtonClass
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Twick Done by a single line only ...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1.Give a class name or id for your image.

2.Then use that name or id in css

3.css

```
image id/ image class
{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Single Line code did the Magic for me

```
img1.Style.Add("OnPreRender", "text-align:center;cursor:pointer;");



 ImageButton img1 = new ImageButton();
                            img1.ImageUrl = "images/ablue.GIF";
                            //Changed on Sept-11 to show the Cursor as Hand of Imagebutton
                            img1.Style.Add("OnPreRender", "text-align:center;cursor:pointer;");
                            img1.Height = 14;
                            img1.Width = 20;
                            img1.ToolTip = "Image Available";
                            img1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return SetId('" + e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString() + "');");
                            e.Row.Cells[16].Controls.Add(img1);
```